# Creating part of an image as example for A2 print

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-production, image-editing

I need to be able to supply a photo of part of a large print -mainly A2. Larger prints will be produced by a commercial company. I suppose I need to set the printer page size to A2 and then view it on my display 20inch. Then I use the marquee tool to create a sample of the image?
But how do I display an actual A2 size on PS?

**EDIT**:  To clarify. This is my situation.

I am an artist. To market my prints clients either buy A3 or smaller prints. I use my own printer up to A3, for larger than A3 I use a commercial printer. Clients who may want to buy large prints need to see what a large print is like.  So I want to send them a sample print which will be a selection made from the print.

What I need to do is create a sample print which will be part of the print they are thinking of purchasing. The sample print will be exactly the same as a part of the A2 print - not just a zoomed in selection.

Comment: I don't understand what is being asked here.

Comment: I don't understand the question either. Perhaps using Photoshop for printing is confusing when it comes to physical size. I would use InDesign or Illustrator for something like this.

Comment: Several things confuse me here. Why do you mention the size of your screen? Why do you talk about "displaying an actual A2 size"? If this question is about printing samples of images, I can't see how your screen is relevant. Also in your addition I don't understand what you mean is the difference between "a part of the A2 print" and "not just a zoomed in selection". Do you want to print an A3 with part of the original A2 at the same scale or do you want to print the whole A2 scaled down to A3? (And again I strongly advice you to use a layout program like InDesign for things like this.)

Comment: So you want to size your image to A2 and then print an A3 size portion of that image as a sample ? Increase your Image Size (Image> Image Size) to A2 size and then crop it down to A3. The result is a part of an A2 image printed on A3 paper.

Comment: @Kyle Yes except that I want to print or post using ordinary mail a selection of a part of an A2 print onto 13x18cm paper.  My prints larger than A3 are created for me by a commercial fine Art printer. For example, I have a large print sent to me by the commercial company. I then select part of that large print and cut it out of the print using scissors. That sample is then posted to the client. the client will be looking at a sample of the artwork which has been printed.

Comment: Now I'm even more confused.  You cut out a sample of an A2 print from a print shop. But do you want to stop doing this and instead print the sample yourself?

Comment: Years later.. what I would do.. is get one large print... take a straight edge and an Xacto and cut it into equal sections... as samples, send one of these sections. The larger the print or fewer the sections, the larger the samples are.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand "a zoomed-in selection". But let's try to give you an option.

Prepare an A2 document at the real size and the resolution of your images, so they are not resampled when using this new file.

Make a "collage". For example: As the file is A2, you could make a collage of 16 A6 postcards or 32 A7 size, Copy a selection that is representative of your work, and send one of these samples.

Use the exact same resolution as the final print.

Send this file to your provider.

This way you will have a sample of the exact same paper as the one that will be delivered, the exact same ink and colors, and the resolution.

I am not mentioning details on how to prepare your file, because I do not know what the printing company needs.

See if you need some margins if you need to crop your file to the exact same dimensions, or even if you need to send a PDF file instead of a JPG or TIFF file.

---

Do not use your printer. The paper, the ink, the quality will be diferent. It can be better or worst but will be diferent.

Of course, you can also print some postcards in your printer as a sample of your A3 prints.